# EF6 Code First FOREIGN KEY Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, properties, navigation

my code is simple i have 3 classes :

```
[DataContract]
public class PhaseDocument : BaseModelEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the phase document identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The phase document identifier.
    /// </value>
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid PhaseDocumentId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the dynamic phase header identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The dynamic phase header identifier.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid DynamicPhaseHeaderId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the version.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The version.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public  int Version   { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the description.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The description.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the HTML code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The HTML code.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string HtmlCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the attachments identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The attachments identifier.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public int AttachmentsId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the child of.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The child of.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember]
    public Guid? ChildOf { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the work flow instance identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The work flow instance identifier.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember]
    public Guid WorkFlowInstanceId { get; set; } 
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the phase modules.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The phase modules.
    /// </value>
    public virtual ICollection<PhaseModule> PhaseModules { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the dynamic phase header.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The dynamic phase header.
    /// </value>
    public virtual DynamicPhaseHeader DynamicPhaseHeader { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the attachments.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The attachments.
    /// </value>
    public virtual Attachments Attachments { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the work flow instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The work flow instance.
    /// </value>
    public virtual WorkFlowInstance WorkFlowInstance { get; set; }


}
public class PhaseModule :BaseModelEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the phase module identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The phase module identifier.
    /// </value>
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid PhaseModuleId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the description.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The description.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the version.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The version.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the phase document identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The phase document identifier.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid PhaseDocumentId { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the HTML code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The HTML code.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string HtmlCode { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the order position.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The order position.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public int OrderPosition { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the child of.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The child of.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember]
    public Guid? ChildOf { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the work flow instance identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The work flow instance identifier.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember]
    public Guid WorkFlowInstanceId { get; set; } 


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the phase document.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The phase document.
    /// </value>
    public virtual PhaseDocument PhaseDocument { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the phase pages.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The phase pages.
    /// </value>
    public virtual ICollection<PhasePage>  PhasePages { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the work flow instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The work flow instance.
    /// </value>
    public virtual WorkFlowInstance WorkFlowInstance { get; set; }

}
 public class PhasePage :BaseModelEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the phase page identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The phase page identifier.
    /// </value>
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid PhasePageId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the description.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The description.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the phase module identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The phase module identifier.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid PhaseModuleId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the work flow instance identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The work flow instance identifier.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember]
    public Guid WorkFlowInstanceId { get; set; } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the HTML code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The HTML code.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string HtmlCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the order position.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The order position.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public int OrderPosition { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the child of.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The child of.
    /// </value>
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid? ChildOf { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the fields.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The fields.
    /// </value>
    public virtual ICollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the phase module.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The phase module.
    /// </value>
    public virtual PhaseModule PhaseModule { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the work flow instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The work flow instance.
    /// </value>
    public virtual WorkFlowInstance WorkFlowInstance { get; set; }
}
```

A Phase document can have one or more Phase Module.
A Phase Module can have one or more Phase Page.
All can have a WorkFlowInstance,

my ef configurations class are :

```
  public PhaseDocumentConfiguration(string schema = "dbo")
    {
        ToTable(schema + ".PhaseDocuments");
        HasKey(x => x.PhaseDocumentId);

        Property(x => x.PhaseDocumentId).HasColumnName("PhaseDocumentId").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Description).HasColumnName("Description").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.Version).HasColumnName("Version").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.HtmlCode).HasColumnName("HtmlCode").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.AttachmentsId).HasColumnName("AttachmentsId").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.ChildOf).HasColumnName("ChildOf").IsOptional();


        //BaseModelEntityProp
        Property(x => x.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.CreatedOn).HasColumnName("CreatedOn").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.ModifiedBy).HasColumnName("ModifiedBy").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.LastModify).HasColumnName("LastModify").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.IsDeleted).HasColumnName("IsDeleted").IsRequired();

        // Foreign keys
        HasRequired(a => a.CreatedByUser)
            .WithMany(b => b.PhaseDocument_CreatedBy)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CreatedBy)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // FK_XXXX_CreatedByUser
        HasRequired(a => a.ModifiedByUser)
            .WithMany(b => b.PhaseDocument_ModifiedBy)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ModifiedBy)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // FK_XXXX_ModifiedByUser

        HasRequired(a => a.Attachments)
            .WithMany(r=>r.PhaseDocuments)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.AttachmentsId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasRequired(a => a.DynamicPhaseHeader)
            .WithMany(r => r.PhaseDocuments)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.DynamicPhaseHeaderId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasRequired(a => a.WorkFlowInstance)
           .WithMany(r => r.PhaseDocument)
           .HasForeignKey(c => c.WorkFlowInstanceId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
public PhaseModuleConfiguration(string schema = "dbo")
    {
        ToTable(schema + ".PhaseModules");
        HasKey(x => x.PhaseModuleId);

        Property(x => x.PhaseModuleId).HasColumnName("PhaseModuleId").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Description).HasColumnName("Description").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.Version).HasColumnName("Version").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.PhaseDocumentId).HasColumnName("PhaseDocumentId").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.HtmlCode).HasColumnName("HtmlCode").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.OrderPosition).HasColumnName("OrderPosition").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.ChildOf).HasColumnName("ChildOf").IsOptional();

        //BaseModelEntityProp
        Property(x => x.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.CreatedOn).HasColumnName("CreatedOn").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.ModifiedBy).HasColumnName("ModifiedBy").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.LastModify).HasColumnName("LastModify").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.IsDeleted).HasColumnName("IsDeleted").IsRequired();

        // Foreign keys
        HasRequired(a => a.CreatedByUser)
            .WithMany(b => b.PhaseModule_CreatedBy)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CreatedBy)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // FK_XXXX_CreatedByUser
        HasRequired(a => a.ModifiedByUser)
            .WithMany(b => b.PhaseModule_ModifiedBy)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ModifiedBy)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // FK_XXXX_ModifiedByUser

        HasRequired(a => a.PhaseDocument)
            .WithMany(r=>r.PhaseModules)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.PhaseDocumentId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasRequired(a => a.WorkFlowInstance)
           .WithMany(r => r.PhaseModule)
           .HasForeignKey(c => c.WorkFlowInstanceId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
 public PhasePageConfiguration(string schema = "dbo")
    {
        ToTable(schema + ".PhasePages");
        HasKey(x => x.PhasePageId);

        Property(x => x.PhasePageId).HasColumnName("WardId").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Description).HasColumnName("Description").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.PhaseModuleId).HasColumnName("PhaseModuleId").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.HtmlCode).HasColumnName("HtmlCode").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.OrderPosition).HasColumnName("OrderPosition").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.ChildOf).HasColumnName("ChildOf").IsOptional();

        //BaseModelEntityProp
        Property(x => x.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.CreatedOn).HasColumnName("CreatedOn").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.ModifiedBy).HasColumnName("ModifiedBy").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.LastModify).HasColumnName("LastModify").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.IsDeleted).HasColumnName("IsDeleted").IsRequired();

        // Foreign keys
        HasRequired(a => a.CreatedByUser)
            .WithMany(b => b.PhasePage_CreatedBy)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CreatedBy)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // FK_XXXX_CreatedByUser
        HasRequired(a => a.ModifiedByUser)
            .WithMany(b => b.PhasePage_ModifiedBy)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ModifiedBy)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // FK_XXXX_ModifiedByUser

        HasRequired(a => a.PhaseModule)
            .WithMany(r=>r.PhasePages)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.PhaseModuleId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasRequired(a => a.WorkFlowInstance)
           .WithMany(r => r.PhasePage)
           .HasForeignKey(c => c.WorkFlowInstanceId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Now if i run teh application i've

> Server Error in '/' Application.

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.PhaseModules_dbo.WorkFlowInstances_WorkFlowInstanceId' on table 'PhaseModules' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please

i've already added .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); but nothing changed.

I'm missing something? 
TNX!

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but did you migrate after adding that? If not, you need to do so. However, EF often fails modifying foreign keys, so you might need to go directly to the database to affect the change. Or, if you do run into issues, and you haven't got any data you're afraid to lose, it would probably be simplest to throw the database away and let EF create it again.

Comment: Hi Chris, already done! but nothing changed! for you the code seams to be correct?

Comment: Well, if there was a problem, it would be in your architecture, which I can't speak to. Simply, you just have a foreign key "loop", for lack of a better word. At some point, you have to break the cascade, or the database can't determine which object to delete first. What was included in the migration? It's possible EF won't generate code to actually fix this, and you may have to make the change manually.

Comment: why you mixed data annotation and fluent api? It's really messy.. you can leverage the conventions..the less code written, the less code to maintain.

Comment: Really Larry ? so i can do all whithout configuration classes ? can you help me to learn the conventions ? Maybe an example based on my code is really appreciated!

Comment: @MVCisMyBestFriend are you trolling? Here's the convention doc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj679962.aspx

Comment: Larry Sorry! TNX for the link, i'm not trolling! My problem is not solved do  you agree?

Comment: in the modelbuilder method, try remove the cascading delete convention by doing modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

Comment: in the model PharseDocument has a 1:1 relationship with WorkflowInstance, but in the fluent api it has a 1 to multiple relationship.